# Test Class Not Covering Return

Tags: apex, unit-test, class

My test class doesn't seem to cover any of the return methods within my apex class, therefore only giving me 69% code coverage, and I can't deploy into production.

Apex Class - Main

```apex
public with sharing class EventInteractionRedirectController {
    
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=false)
    public static string GetInteractionIdForEvent(string eventId, boolean updated){
        
        List<Interaction__c> matchingInteraction = [
            select Id
            from Interaction__c
            where Event_Id__c = :eventId
        ];

        // Do an update so an interaction is automatically created
        if (matchingInteraction.size() == 0) {
            
            if (updated) {
                return null;
            }

            List<Event> matchingEvent = [
                select Id
                from Event
                where Id = :eventId
            ];

            if (matchingEvent.size() > 0) {
                EventInteractionProcessor.ProcessEventsImmediate(new Set<Id>{eventId});
                return GetInteractionIdForEvent(eventId, true);
            }

            return null;
        }

        return matchingInteraction[0].Id;

    }

}
```

Test Class

```apex
@isTest
public class TestEventInteractionRedirect {
    
    @isTest
    private static void EventWithInteraction_ReturnInteractionId() {

        Account testAccount = new Account(
            Name = 'Test Account'
        );
        insert testAccount;

        Event event = new Event(
            Subject = 'Test Event',
            StartDateTime = DateTime.now(),
            EndDateTime = DateTime.now().addDays(1),
            WhatId = testAccount.Id
        );
        insert event;

        System.assertEquals(
            EventInteractionRedirectController.GetInteractionIdForEvent(event.Id, false),
            [select id from Interaction__c][0].Id
            );

    }

    @isTest
    private static void EventWithoutInteraction_ReturnNewInteractionId() {

        Account testAccount = new Account(
            Name = 'Test Account'
        );
        insert testAccount;

        Event event = new Event(
            Subject = 'Test Event',
            StartDateTime = DateTime.now(),
            EndDateTime = DateTime.now().addDays(1),
            WhatId = testAccount.Id
        );
        insert event;

        // We need to delete the existing interaction cause other trigger
        delete [select Id from Interaction__c];

        Id interactionId = EventInteractionRedirectController.GetInteractionIdForEvent(event.Id, false);

        System.assert(interactionId != null);

    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Going by the blue lines in the coverage, it seems like the method is terminated at line 26, probably because the `ProcessEventsImmediate()` throws an exception. Are your tests passing?

Comment: They are and providing 69% coverage on the class.

Answer (score 0):

1. In your test class create test function to cover the following
   GetInteractionIdForEvent(event.Id, **true**) this will cover your line#16
2. Create another test function with an eventId which is already existing in the Interaction__c  which give you  matchingInteraction().size >0; then that will give a cover for your line#30